# Extract parents from a File up to the "root" ("c:\" or "/")

Tags: java, file-io

I need to extract all available parents for a file. For example, i have a file like "c:\users\admin\Downloads\1\2\3\4\5\test.stub", i need to add any parent to a list of Files, that it contains:

```
c:\users\admin\Downloads\1\2\3\4\5\
c:\users\admin\Downloads\1\2\3\4\
c:\users\admin\Downloads\1\2\3\
...
c:\
```

Any Ideas how i could make that?

Thanks in Advance,

Flo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
File f = new File("c:\\users\\admin\\Downloads\\1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\");
while(getParent() != null){
   System.out.println(f.getPath());
   f = f.getParentFile();
}
```

[`getParent()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent%28%29) returns the path of the parent directory (or null if there is no parent).
[`getParentFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile%28%29) returns the parent directory as a File.

---

**Resources :**

- [Javadoc - File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)